# Android Layouts by screen size, not dpi

Tags: android, layout

I have seen that my apps have some issues on smaller devices, as the same DPI on an 5.1 inch device can also be on a 3.1 inch device. This causes problems as it forces some of the layout objects off the screen. According to google:

[image]

And additionally;

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

However, there are some issues with this ancient setup;

My S6 Edge has a DPI of 640 so it classifies in this system as a 7 inch tablet. This is way off, as it is only 5.1 inches.

And I have an 8 inch tablet with 320 DPI, which is equal to 'a typical phone'.

So suddenly, phones and tablets have swapped positions; Therefore it makes the *dpi system useless, as content goes off screen.

I therefore need to go by screen size, as that is what really counts. I cannot seem to find anything on this, I looked through the documentation but I could not find anything. I don't want to create one layout for each 0.1 inch, but per 1.0(ish) inches. Especially for smaller devices this is an issue, as content goes off screen. The sizes themselves are fine, actually but the content going off the screen is a major issue.

I have seen on the pre-launch reports that smaller devices start to push menu buttons off the screen. For an instance on the tested Nexus 5, the ad is pushed off.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are resource qualifiers for screen sizes:

```
layout-small
layout-medium
layout-large
layout-xlarge

drawable-small...
```

However, I believe your understanding of how dpi system becomes useless is a bit distorted. The system was put in place to greatly help in displaying proper asset as per screen capability. For eg. if you try to put a xxhdpi image on your 320 dpi tablet, the system will basically have to drop pixels to display it properly. If you design your layouts using screen size you will run into similar issues since, screen height and width in dpi (along which you will probably base your display) will not depend on size but, rather the screen density.

Personally, to make sure my layouts look proper I test them on a smaller screen phone like Nexus S and also on a newer phone like Nexus 6P all the while keeping a single layout file.

Comment: so I just create new folders named that? does it work the way I think it does, that if it isn't a custom layout created for(example) layout-xlarge, it goes with layout/...?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: But the best to use is actually the *dpi system?

Comment: Yeah. I usually create just a single layout file for a form factor (phone/ tablet/etc)

Comment: So if I create custom layouts for the 'problem' platforms that is all I need to do? Using the *dpi system?

Comment: I didn't get your last statement.

Comment: as I mentioned above, the reason for this question is that some items in the layouts get pushed off the screen on smaller devices.  I design the layouts using the 5.1 inch 'phone' inside Android Studio. This causes problems on smaller devices, so do I just create for an instance 240dpi(hdpi) folder or create a small/medium folder and create the layout for the smaller phones in there? Which one should I use? And the DPI system, you said I had it wrong. How did I get it wrong? If a 640 dpi layout is displayed on a 640 dpi 3 inch phone, will it appear just like on a 7 inch tablet?(which according

Comment: When you are designing your layouts for a given form factor, don't design them such that they take up entire screen size on any one particular screen size. Design them so that they scale properly based on any screen size. Your layouts will help you in this. (For eg: Relativelayout has aligntoBottom, linearLayout has layout_weight, etc etc.). This is the general idea of tacking device fragmentation in android.

Comment: The whole consept there is really hard, as not all devices are the same size(not all phones are 1440 x 2560). But I'm going to go with the *dpi system for creating better layouts. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: If you have any trouble arranging them, feel free to SO them.

Comment: I added a custom layout using the sw<N>dp system, and I really see I got the *dpi system wrong now.